# Menu not persisting selection (Angular v10) (HTML)

Tags: html, angular

I have a simple dropdown menu

```
          <ng-container matColumnDef="sla2">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SLA2</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">On Time</button>
              <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item>On Time</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>Late</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>Missing</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>NDR</button>
              </mat-menu>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
```

The only problem is, when I select a different value (e.g. 'Late') it is not showing it, and instead still shows 'On Time'. How can I have a menu, where I select a value, then that value is the one that is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a variable in your ts file like:

```
value = 'On Time';
```

And now you can use it in html:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{value}}</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="value = 'On Time'">On Time</button>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="value = 'Late'">Late</button>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="value = 'Missing'">Missing</button>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="value = 'NDR'">NDR</button>
</mat-menu>
```

In your case it should be like:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="sla2">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SLA2</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{value}}</button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="value = 'On Time'">On Time</button>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="value = 'Late'">Late</button>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="value = 'Missing'">Missing</button>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="value = 'NDR'">NDR</button>
          </mat-menu>
        </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This works! However, it puts every rows value as the same, instead of just the row I changed. How can I fix it to only the row I changed?

Comment: You can make the value object. Then you can modify properties of this object.
Example:

values = {
row1: "On Time",
row2: "Late"
}